# axios delete method takes too long to complete

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I am calling the web api `delete` method in `axios.delete()` and it takes too long.. in contrast if I call same web api method using `postman` response is immediate.
has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

use `fetch` ES6

Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Is native, and so fast :D